# ® turned to � Character in my HTML, and the source is from XML

Tags: html, xml, vbscript, character-encoding

I'm am doing the following, and got the � showing up in my HTML

1) Server script send XML to get the data

2) Got XML data returned back in UTF-8 (® is appear fine at this point in VBScript)

3) Send the data in json format to JavaScript (check the json with Firebug in Firefox, and ® is showing correctly.

4) Use JavaScript parse the JSON, how I see "®" as � in my HTML.

** I have sent the JSON in UTF-8
** I have specified the HTML page to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Some code examples would be nice.

Comment: What do you mean by "specified the html page as utf-8".  Have you just added a meta tag or have you saved the page as utf-8 rather than ascii.  If you don't know what I mean here, open the html page in Notepad, select "Save As" from the file menu and you'll find a character encoding dropdown

Comment: I would recommend inspecting what **bytes** are being sent around. The fact that something displays ® doesn't mean it's a 2-byte UTF-8 byte sequence. My bet is on VBScript generating non-UTF-8 JSON.